# Nodemailer-juice img tag only displays width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, nodemailer

I have a problem, I'm trying to set an image inside the html of nodemailer styling it with nodemailer-juice. Even though I can style everything, when it comes to images I can only set width and height, not position, or margin, etc. Does anybody know why? Thanks a lot in adnvance.

```
  <style>img {position:relative; height:10em;}</style>
      <img src="cid:abstract@abstract.com">
```

it only takes height